# Configuring IIS for SAML Authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, saml

I have IIS 7 (Windows Server 2008 R2) and TFIM front-ending the users so that by the time the request hits IIS there's a SAML token presented via WS-Fed.

What I am trying to understand is, what's needed to be installed or configured on the IIS side to consume this token?

Do you have to change the Authentication module in IIS to something else? Anything else?

Do I need to install anything in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Microsoft world, applications that use an STS (like ADFS or TFIM) that uses the WS-Federation protocol to authenticate use WIF to process the claims that are enclosed in the SAML token.

There's nothing IIS specific.

Comment: So as long as the ASP.Net app uses WIF it's good? You sure there's nothing on the IIS side in the Authentication module? Does it have to be set to Windows Authentication or something else?

Comment: It depends - what STS are you using?

Comment: It's TFIM. What I am curious about is how I set up the trust between the application hosted in IIS and the TFIM STS? For exmaple in SharePoint you'd import the TFIM exported SSL certificate, but in IIS I am not sure.

Comment: For ASP.NET you use WIF. What version of VS are you using? e.g. for VS 2012 you would use the "Identity and Access Tool". This produces client metadata which you the import into TFIM. There is nothing specific you do to IIS itself.